# Problems with formatting multicolumn tables

Tags: tables, formatting, multicolumn

I am having problems in centering the text in a table using multicolumn. This is the table I have created:

```
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Metric}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{FFNN}\vline&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{CNN}\vline\\
& In-Sample & Out-of-Sample & In-Sample & Out-of-Sample\\\hline
RMSE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline MAE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
MDA & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline $\text{R}^2$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and this is what I get after compiling:

[image]

The problem is that the two column titles, "FFNN" and "CNN" are not centered with respect to the 'In-Sample' and 'Out-of-Sample' columns below. Is there a way to center them without changing the layout of the table?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the `FFNN` and `CNN` header strings to be centered between columns 2/3 and 4/5, respectively, the four data columns need to have equal widths. One way to achieve this is with the help of the `w` column type, which is provided by the `array` package.

You may also want to rethink why it's even necessary to center the `FFNN` and `CNN` strings on the vertical lines that separate columns 2/3 and 4/5. If you get rid of all vertical lines and use fewer but well-spaced horizontal lines, it's not really necessary to pay attention to the unequal column widths.

The first table in the following screenshot reproduces the OP's screenshot. The second table employs the `w` column type to center the `FFNN` and `CNN` headers; observe that despite the fact that these headers are now centered over the pairs of columns, the "look" still isn't balanced since the strings in the sub-headers -- "In-Sample" and "Out-of-Sample" -- have rather different widths. The third table does away with the vertical lines, getting rid of the need for equal-width columns in the process.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,multirow,booktabs}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Out-of-Sample}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{4}{c|}}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Metric}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{FFNN}\vline&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{CNN}\vline\\
& In-Sample & Out-of-Sample & In-Sample & Out-of-Sample\\\hline
RMSE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline MAE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
MDA & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline R\textsuperscript{2} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{4}{wc{\mylen}|}}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Metric}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{FFNN}\vline&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{CNN}\vline\\
& In-Sample & Out-of-Sample & In-Sample & Out-of-Sample\\\hline
RMSE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline MAE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
MDA & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline R\textsuperscript{2} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l cccc @{}}
\toprule
Metric & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FFNN} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{CNN} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& In-Sample & Out-of-Sample & In-Sample & Out-of-Sample\\
\midrule
RMSE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
MAE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
MDA & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
R\textsuperscript{2} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a very clean and elegant solution! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The "FFNN" and "CNN" are indeed centered, the problem lies in the widths of the "In-Sample" and "Out-of-Sample" columns. Using `\widthof` from the `calc` package we can make "In-Sample" be in a box of the same width as "Out-of-Sample" which will result in proper centering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc} %<--
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Metric}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{FFNN}\vline&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{CNN}\vline\\
&\makebox[\widthof{Out-of-Sample}][c]{In-Sample} & Out-of-Sample &\makebox[\widthof{Out-of-Sample}][c]{In-Sample} & Out-of-Sample\\\hline%<--
RMSE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline MAE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
MDA & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline $\text{R}^2$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two version of your table written by use of the `tabularray` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\newlength\mycolwidth

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \settowidth\mycolwidth{Out-of-Sample}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,3-Z}, vlines,
             colspec={c *{4}{Q[c, wd=\mycolwidth]} },
             column{2-Z} = {colsep=4pt}
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Metric
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{c} FFNN
            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    CNN
                    &                       \\
        & In-Sample
            & Out-of-Sample
                & In-Sample
                    & Out-of-Sample         \\
RMSE    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4                     \\
MAE     & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4                     \\
MDA     & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4                     \\
R\textsuperscript{2} 
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4                     \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \settowidth\mycolwidth{Out-of-Sample}
\begin{tblr}{column{2-Z} = {colsep=3pt},
             colspec={@{} l *{4}{Q[c, wd=\mycolwidth]} @{}},
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Metric
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{c} FFNN
            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    CNN
                    &                       \\
    \cmidrule[r] {2-3}  
    \cmidrule[l] {4-5}
        & In-Sample
            & Out-of-Sample
                & In-Sample
                    & Out-of-Sample         \\
    \midrule
RMSE    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4                     \\
MAE     & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4                     \\
MDA     & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4                     \\
R\textsuperscript{2}
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want the columns 2 and 3 with different widths (idem for 4 and 5) and, despite that difference, `FFNN` centered according the rule between the columns 2 and 3 (idem for `CNN` above the rule between the columns 4 and 5), it's possible to program a command `\BiBlock` in `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which does the job automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \BiBlock { m }
  {
    \Block{1-2}{}
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl 
      { 
        \__willis_myblock:nnn 
          { \int_use:c { c@iRow } } 
          { \int_eval:n { \int_use:c { c@jCol } + 1 } } 
          { #1 } 
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__willis_myblock:nnn
  { \tikz \node [baseline=base] at ( #1.5 -| #2 ) { #3 } ; }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[vlines]
\hline
\Block{2-1}{Metric}&
\BiBlock{FFNN}& &
\BiBlock{CNN}\\
& In-Sample & Out-of-Sample & In-Sample & Out-of-Sample\\\hline
RMSE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline MAE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
MDA & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline $\text{R}^2$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

The same with the horizontal rules of `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \BiBlock { m }
  {
    \Block{1-2}{}
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl 
      { 
        \__willis_myblock:nnn 
          { \int_use:c { c@iRow } } 
          { \int_eval:n { \int_use:c { c@jCol } + 1 } } 
          { #1 } 
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__willis_myblock:nnn
  { \tikz \node [baseline=base] at ( #1.5 -| #2 ) { #3 } ; }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
\Block{2-1}{Metric}&
\BiBlock{FFNN}& &
\BiBlock{CNN}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-3}  
\cmidrule(l){4-5}
& In-Sample & Out-of-Sample & In-Sample & Out-of-Sample\\
\midrule
RMSE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ MAE & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
MDA & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ $\text{R}^2$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]